# Receiving "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" from Sauce Labs

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, saucelabs

I am running a test against the following page: 
http://hulking-eland-1517.vagrantshare.com/casl/index.php?r=signup

and trying to select an element in the dropdown: 
$this->select($this->byId('card-exp-month'))->selectOptionByValue('12');

Whenever I run this against a local instance of selenium server, it works fine. When I run it in sauce labs (browserName=firefox, desiredCapabilities=[version=15, platform=Windows 2012]), I get the following exception:

PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Anyone have any idea what is happening or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the screenshot captured by Saucelabs show? I am thinking you need to wait until visible.

Comment: Yes it works in local because it's faster than on the internet, so just add a little delay to let the webpage load

Answer (score 0):

The exception details the issue clearly, it means your selected element is not in **visible** status (is hidden/disabled), you need to modify your script and take some **needed action** to get it in ready-state-to-receive-actions.

I tried to enter your provide link but it's not accessible.